# Is there a correlation between the type of a company/industry and the software engineering rigor?

Tags: business, standards, engineering

I would like the answer to explain what impact, if any, does the type of company/industry have on the rigor, depth and breadth with which software engineering is practiced. The best would be some links to support the answer with references.

As a control point, let's declare an assumption that a company which follows the SWEBOK or CMMI (any level) is doing 100% (the best) whereas one which does not follow anything at all is 0% (worst).

Would it be possible to find out what companies or what industries score highest, average, and lowest?

**EDIT:**
CMMI (any level) refers to any organization which is CMMI certified.

**EDIT 2:** The middle paragraph specifies that a company which follows some rigorous software engineering standard should score higher than a company which doesn't.

**EDIT 3:** The SWEBOK is not only organizing content. It does [much more](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/swebok/objectives), i.e. the **SWEBOK characterizes the contents of software engineering body of knowledge**.

The **SWEBOK promotes a consistent view of software engineering worldwide** which is the main point. It is aimed at both practitioners and academics, individuals and organizations. For example, see the [CSDP](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/certification/csdp) and consider [companies who hire them](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/certification/Employers-Requiring-CSDA/P). These are the companies that follow the SWEBOK.

**EDIT 4:** Note that the answer should tell us about industries or companies that follow some rigorous software engineering standard in the prescribed depth and breath, and those who don't. What is the correlation between the type of company/industry and their software engineering rigor?

Throwing in a bunch of links for reference would be great.

Comment: If any level of CMMI is doing 100%, why are there 5 levels of CMMI compliance?

Comment: @Caleb any level of CMMI, apart from "incomplete", is a satisfactory evidence that the company practices software engineering in compliance with some standard. Hence, 100%.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are close votes against this question. But, I have two problems with statements in it. First, one does not "follow the SWEBOK". The SWEBOK is a method of organizing the knowledge that exists within the field of software engineering in a logical manner, and then the Guide to the SWEBOK provides summaries and citations for the best references for information on that area. As far as CMMI goes, it's a framework and collection of practices that lead to a successful project that can be followed in various ways, whole or part, staged or continuous deployment of the practices.

Comment: Note that the answer should tell us about industries or companies that follow some software engineering standard in the prescribed depth and breath, and those who don't. Throwing in a bunch of links for reference would be great.

Comment: Within CMMI, every organization can realize each practice in their own way. There's really no "standard" other than that you are doing the defined activities that are deemed important to successful engineering projects in some way and providing objective evidence of doing them. There's absolutely no measure of how well they are performed or how rigorous the company is in terms of following them, especially since there are criteria for which projects in an organization are assessed - it's entirely possible that entire projects are not assessed in a CMMI audit.

Comment: @Thomas ad. 1 The SWEBOK Guide is typically abbreviated "SWEBOK" at the IEEE CS website (http://www.computer.org/portal/web/swebok/home Volunteers are in the process of refreshing the Guide to the Software Engineering Body of Knowledge (SWEBOK)) and elsewhere (i.e. IEEE papers).

Comment: In summary, your entire middle paragraph is based on a false assumption. You also need to consider industry-specific standards and regulations that define how projects are implemented. For example, AS9100 quality guidelines in the aerospace industry or various defense and military regulations in the defense sector (which could be stacked in defense contractors in the aerospace industry).

Comment: @Thomas ad. 2 The CMMI certificate for any level is only awarded when the CMMI is followed as rigorously as defined in the framework. Further, to qualify for a higher level (i.e. level 4) all lower level (i.e. level 3) processes have to be in place.

Comment: @MarekCruz CMMI isn't a development process, but only a set of requirements that can be applied to whatever process you use. Those requirements are more rigorous with increasing levels of CMMI compliance. It certainly doesn't make sense to declare that processes that achieve CMMI level 1 and those that achieve CMMI level 5 are somehow equally rigorous.

Comment: As a software engineer who works extensively in CMMI, that's not true for [the staged deployment of the CMMI framework](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/library/assets/cepeda-cmmi.pdf). However, the certification process is also different. You do get audited and assessed, but the organization is able to choose different sections and achieve a maturity level in each particular area instead of across the board.

Comment: @Thomas Oh, the middle paragraph. That is to specify what I am asking, i.e. I appreciate it as 100% when a company follows a standard like SWEBOK or CMMI (any level). SWEBOK can be followed by hiring CSDPs, for example. EDIT: I know what's CMMI. If a company follows other rigorous software engineering standards, I'd still assign 100% for the purpose of this question. But if a company for example does not have any project management, but has requirements analysis and software design, that could be 50%, etc. It depends on what data you have available, if any. I only want some answer and link.

Comment: The SWEBOK is a method of organizing knowledge and making it accessible. From the [About SWEBOK page](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/swebok/about): `The Guide to the Software Engineering Body of Knowledge (SWEBOK) describes generally accepted knowledge about software engineering. Its 10 knowledge areas summarize basic concepts and include a reference list pointing to the detailed information.` It's a directory of topics. The only time that I've seen the phrase "follow the SWEBOK" is with regards to academic programs and curricula development to ensure coverage of the breadth of the field..

Comment: @ThomasOwens I voted to close because the question seems to want to quantify "software engineering rigor", but there's no indication of how one might do that. It seems especially unclear given that the OP considers all levels of CMMI to be equally rigorous. What would a "50%" rating mean? There's also no indication of what "the type of a company/industry" could mean. Big vs. small? Economic sector? There are so many different criteria by which one might categorize companies or industries.

Comment: @Thomas where does the text you quote say "SWEBOK is a method of organizing knowledge and making it accessible"? You are making a logical fallacy. The text however says "The Guide to the Software Engineering Body of Knowledge (SWEBOK)" and uses the term "SWEBOK" interchangeably with "SWEBOK Guide". Also note that I clearly wrote "CMMI (any level)" which means "across the board", not in each particular area instead.

Comment: @Thomas FYI SWEBOK is an internationally accepted standard ISO/IEC TR 19759:2005 which defines a generally accepted knowledge in Software Engineering. Its primary purpose is not to organize knowledge and make it accessible, that is only one related aspect. You have to ask questions such as what knowledge does it present, how was that knowledge accumulated, and why. Also the number of KAs is higher than you said in the V3 which is coming out this year. // The purpose of the SWEBOK is to standardize the software engineering practice and define its generally accepted body of knowledge.

Comment: @Caleb these details are deliberately undefined for better compatibility with any data an answered could have. Would you reformat your data for me if I defined specifically "let's consider the size of the company"? Of course you wouldn't.

Comment: I disagree with the closure of this question.  Simply because it may be difficult to answer does not mean it should be closed.  It is certainly on topic.  I reopened it.

Comment: > As a control point, let's declare an assumption that a company which follows the SWEBOK or CMMI (any level) is doing 100% Given that any organisation that develops software is at least CMMI level 1 ([by definition](http://tynerblain.com/blog/2006/03/10/foundation-series-cmmi-levels-explained/)), **all** software developing companies are at 100% by your measure.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that an industry that can't afford failure is more rigorous than another one that can.

The most illustrative example of this is aerospace vs. web design.

The software of a spacecraft can't fail or it falls and hundred million dollars are thrown away. If it doesn't fall, nobody will go up there and fix it (patching is possible to some extend, as long as the bug is not in the patch handler and the antennas and solar panels are correctly oriented).

The software of an aircraft can't fail or hundreds of passengers die. But if an error is found   and handled before a failure, software can be fixed and the patch can be sent to all companies operating that plane.

If the software of a web site fails, nobody is hurt, few money is lost and a fix occurs within a day, if not within an hour.

In aerospace, every task from the system requirements to the final product is verified over and over, software validation of a few thousand lines needs several years. Despite all of that, systems are duplicated or triplicated from basic hardware components to whole satellites (e.g., see [Iridium satellite constellation, in-orbit spares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium_satellite_constellation#In-orbit_spares)). In that process, CMMi, ISO9000, DO-178 and other quality stuff are just a by-product; the rigor is in the process itself, not in how it is controlled.